Migrate APKs into bundle, abi splitting versionCode
I used to work with split abi apks for the various architectures.
A useful trick I used for versioning each apk described here.
ext.abiCodes = ["armeabi": 1, "x86": 2, "armeabi-v7a": 3, "arm64-v8a": 4, "x86_64": 5]

android.applicationVariants.all { variant ->
    variant.outputs.each { output ->
        def baseAbiVersionCode = abiCodes.get(output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI))
        if (baseAbiVersionCode != null) {
            output.versionCodeOverride = baseAbiVersionCode * 1000000 + variant.versionCode
        }
    }
}


However, when migrating to use bundles this trick not working anymore.
Is there any way assigning different versionCode for the various APKs been generated from the bundle file?
Any help would be appreciated.
I have already tried Google this issue, without luck

With the app bundle, you generally only have to publish a single artifact containing all the native libraries, so you only need a single versionCode, not one per ABI.
The Play Console becomes responsible for generating the split APKs that will be shipped to each device based on its architecture, screen density, user languages, etc.
